# Testing/Mocking Custom Console commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I constructed my own simple command, that I want to test.

which basically looks like this:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

class NeatCommand extends Command
{


    protected $signature = 'my:neat:command {input_file : path for a json-formatted file to analyze}';

    protected $description = 'analyze an array of values';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }


    public function handle()
    {

        $inputFile=$this->argument('input_file');
        echo $inputFile;
    }



}
```

So I wrote this simple test:

```
/**
 * @test
 * @group neat
 */
public function commandShowsHelloWorld()
{

    $defaultCommand=Artisan::call('my:neat:command');

}
```

I simple want to test at this stage: there are arguments missing. But when I run it right now, phpunit brings it as an error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) App\Console\Commands\NeatCommandTest::commandShowsHelloWorld
RuntimeException: Not enough arguments.
```

So my question is. How can i mock the whole thing...or say something like `$this->shouldReturn('RuntimeException: Not enough arguments.');` ?

Comment: I am wondering why your test function does not start with 'test', also why not  use @expectedException annotation from phpunit https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException

Comment: yes i got it working with expectedExeption. thanks. and also the @test was there, forgot to write it here.

Comment: What is it you're trying to test? If you're trying to test your code that does the analysis, I'd move that to a separate library & test it using standard unit testing methods. As for testing the `Artisan::call(...)` - I wouldn't bother. The framework stuff (how to call a command, etc.) has already been tested; what hasn't been tested is the custom code you write.

Comment: I am just trying to test if it is delivering the expected. But this example is trivial. Once I add more options, I would have to test what results it brings. I am trying to generate strings form input files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working but adding the @annotation of expected exceptions.

```
/**
 * @test
 * @group neat
 * @expectedException RuntimeException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage Not enough arguments.
 */
public function commandWithoutArgumentsCausesError()
{

    $defaultCommand=Artisan::call('my:neat:command');

}
```